# Reverse order of control alignment in VS 2010 designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

This one is a pure matter of habits. I've been using Visual Studio C++ dialog designer for years. So now I'm working with a .NET C# form designer in VS 2010.

Say, I have the following two controls:

[image]

and I need to align the top one to match the bottom. So in VS C++ designer I would first click on the control that I wanted to adjust, then Ctrl+click on the control that I wanted to adjust to, and then select "Align Lefts" toolbar button:

[image]

which perfectly made sense.

But now in VS 2010, I have to do this process totally in reverse, i.e. first select the control to align to and then select the control being aligned. I know that I'm nitpicking here, but this totally messes me up. I'm constantly doing it in the wrong order, and then have to undo and redo it again. The rhetorical yell that usually comes out is, "*Why, Microsoft! Why?*" But that is not my question here.

Is there some setting, or may a registry fix to make it act like VS C++ designer used to work?

Comment: It seems to align to the control that has the white boxes in its selection frame (top on your screenshot; as opposed to black boxes on all other controls). You can click among the already selected controls to change where the white boxes go, and only then click Align lefts. So order of selection only matters indirectly, in which case there apparently is no setting to control it.

Comment: I would like to rephrase your problem: The behavior you want is **the last selected control should be the adjusted-to control** and the current behavior is **the first selected control is the adjusted-to control**. I really like the latter (the current one). BTW I don't think this does matter much. I don't even use such an editing command. When you use `WPF`, maybe you just need typing to build your UI.

Comment: this behavior look normal to me. Comparing to other software it's how it works. If i want to move an object in Photoshop i don't choose where to move it. I select what i want to move then click when i want to move it to. It's a personal opinion the inverse i find that very confusing.

Comment: Guys, it's not about things being "normal", it's all about our habits.

Comment: Quite old, but interesting question. I shared a solution, maybe it helps future readers or someone can use it as an example to use `ISelectionService`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `ISelectionService` which helps to get or set selected components and also notifies when selection changes.

You can achieve the desired behavior by handling `SelectionChanged` event of the service as follows:

```
private void SelectionSVC_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectionSVC = sender as ISelectionService;
    if (selectionSVC == null) return;
    try
    {
        selectionSVC.SelectionChanged -= SelectionSVC_SelectionChanged;
        if ((Control.ModifierKeys & (Keys.Shift | Keys.Control)) > Keys.None)
        {
            var selection = selectionSVC.GetSelectedComponents()
                .Cast<object>().LastOrDefault();
            if (selection != null)
                selectionSVC.SetSelectedComponents(new[] { selection },
                    SelectionTypes.Primary | SelectionTypes.Add);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        selectionSVC.SelectionChanged += SelectionSVC_SelectionChanged;
    }
}
```

Getting an instance of the service, depends to the context. For example using a VS Package in a designer window , having an instance of `IdesignerHost`:

```
var selectionSVC = (ISelectionService)host.GetService(typeof(ISelectionService));
if (selectionSVC != null)
    selectionSVC.SelectionChanged += SelectionSVC_SelectionChanged;
```